How to make the configuration pushed to the ODL netconf testtool persisted after the testtool's restart?
I am using the ODL netconf testtool for one of my projects and want the configuration pushed to the testtool, including the incremental configuration to be persisted even after restarting the tool.
For now only the initial configuration pushed to the simulator during the start of the tool is persisted, how could the incremental configuration also be persisted? I am running the testtool as docker containers and as I want a large number of them. How could the problem with configuration be resolved?

Have you tried using:
--md-sal true

This switch should instruct the tool to use the md-sal datastore instead of the default simulated datastore. You can find more detailed documentation  here
For a more advanced OpenDaylight-based NETCONF device simulator, I suggest considering the lighty-netconf-simulator

yes, i have tried using --md-sal true, but it didn't help either

Indeed, the --md-sal switch serves as an in-memory datastore. It may be more appropriate to consider using the --initial-config-xml-file option instead.
